# Is it possible to get more than just value from Request.Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls, request.form

I got a site where i'm creating dynamicly a Form this looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td >
        <input name="input1" type="text" value="Muster">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Account</td>
    <td >
        <input name="input2" type="text" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Begin</td>
    <td >
        <input name="input3" type="text" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>End</td>
    <td >
        <input name="input4" type="text" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For retrieving the textboxes I'm using this code snipped:

```
var formControls = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(n => n.Contains(IDPREFIX)).ToList();
```

And the value with `Request.Form.Get(control)`  (foreach over formControls)

Is it somehow possible to read from Request.form if the textbox is readonly?
The problem is i don't have the access to the control anymore, because im doing a postback and i dont render the controls a 2nd time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't found any way to do it with Request.Form.
OS i had to Change the whole code to find Controls on my site.